# <% %> isn't working properly in EJS web pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have a ejs page where I am trying to use the following code:

```
<% dbcon.getProducts().then(results => { %>

<% }).catch(err => { console.log(err) }) %>
```

However, these %><% don't seem to be working. While the ones in the front and the end are blue, the ones in between are grey like they aren't working. The reason I need %><% is so that I could add code in between. However, it doesn't seem to work. I don't know what's wrong and I really need it to work. Also, if there is a better way of doing this I will appreciate any help.

**Update:** 
Basically, What I am trying to do is display a database table to an ejs page. This is my ejs page:

**store.ejs:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>PC Store | Store</title>
    <% include partials/header %>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <% include partials/navbar %>
    </header>
    <main>
        <% dbcon.getProducts().then(results => { %>
        <div class="container">
            <% for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { %>
               <h1><%= results[0] %></h1>
            <% } %>
        </div>
        <% }).catch(err => { console.log(err) }) %>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <% include partials/footer %>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

The code inside the  doesn't want to work.

If I where to use `console.log(results[i]);` it would display the database content in the console. However, it doesn't display it on the ejs web page. Also, the %><% before the `<div>` and after the `</div>` don't seem to work.

Comment: what are the lines in between, that aren't working?

Comment: I wanted to add a for loop inside so that I can display the results, but the %><% are grayed out.

Comment: can you show us what is the forloop code inside? this works: `<% [[1,2,3],[2],[3]].map(num => { %>
    <% num.map(n => { %>
        <h2><%= n %></h2>
    <% }) %>
<% }) %>`

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { results[i] }`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EJS](http://ejs.co/) is only a simple templating language that lets you generate HTML markup with plain JavaScript.

You should probably do the `getProducts()` before and pass the result into the EJS:

**js**

```
const ejs = require('ejs');
const template = require('./template.ejs');

const results = await dbcon.getProducts();
const html = ejs.render(template , { results });
```

**template.ejs**

```
<% results.map(result => result) %>
```

Comment: It isn't displaying on the ejs page and the %> at the end of the first line and <% in the beginning of the last line are not the color blue which means they aren't doing what they are supposed to!

Comment: yeah EJS is only plain renderer we can't/shouldn't do more than rendering with ejs. I have updated my answer